# How to find xpath for date range from linkedin

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I've been experimenting with selenium as a data scraper. I'm trying to get the data from my linkedin profile and fill my cv with that data. It's working fine mostly but I can't figure out how to get the xpath for the date ranges of my previous experience or education.

So on my linkedin I have filled in my previous experience and it says: 
Jobtitle
Company
Dates From - To · amount of time
Location

I can get the jobtitle and the company, I don't need the location. It's just the dates that are giving me trouble. I've tried several xpaths that seemed like they could possibly get me the correct data but I'm stuck with this part. Can anyone help me? I'm sorry if this is a silly question, I've just been trying this as a hobby project so I don't have anyone to ask about this either. Google hasn't helped me further either. I'm actually guessing I misunderstood how xpath works BUT my code for jobtitle and company work fine so I'm confused.

It's for a python project using selenium with Chromedriver. I've tried several xpath's that I'll add as code.

```
period = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal")]/text()').extract_first()

period = sel.xpath('//*[contains(@id, "ember654")]/text()').extract_first()

period = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "197582093")]/text()').extract()
```

I'd really like to get the dates from both my previous jobs, plain text is fine, I think I'll split the from - to later on. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the nodes you are constructing the XPath?

Comment: Ah that's a great idea! Sorry, didn't think of it. Supputuri added it below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the xpath to fetch the dates.

```
//span[.='Dates Employed']/following-sibling::span
```

There are 5 jobs for one of the profile so the xpath matched all the dates in the 5 profiles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I try to get the xpath from the same line (using google Chrome - inspect - rightclick the element - copy xpath) I get a different xpath though: //*[@id="ember1693"]/div[2]/div/h4[1]/span[2] I guess I'm doing it wrong, can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Ok so I tried several things with your provided xpath but when I print I either get an empty [] or I get a variant of '<span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>'. Does this mean the dates are hidden and I can't extract them? Examples of what I tried: `period = sel.xpath('//span[.="Dates Employed"]').extract()` and `period =     ervaringPeriode = sel.xpath('//span[.="Dates Employed"]/text()').extract()`

Comment: I wrote a custom xpath rather using the `copy xpath` option. I believe you are trying to return the dates, right?

Comment: Oh I didn't realise that was an option. I'll look into that! Thanks for the info! Do you know if the output '<span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>' means it's impossible to get the dates?

Comment: You should be able to get the dates. If you are using python+selenium here is the logic. `dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[.='Dates Employed']/following-sibling::span")` then use the `for date in dates: print(date)`